# Sql Server logging rows affected in stored procedure select statement

Tags: sql-server, logging, stored-procedures, row-number

I have a log table in which write various information related to the call to some stored procedures that only contain select statements.
One of this information is the number of rows returned by the stored precedures.

One way to do this would be this:

1. Run the count relative to the final select instruction
2. Insert informations in the log table
3. Carry out the final select instruction

Is there a way to recover rows affected information without making a double query (the first with the count and the second with the select) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get number of rows affected by the last statement that was executed.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Based off your comment, Here is an edit containing an example where the select statement is still the output of the stored procedure. The insert to the log table is after the select statement, so the `@@ROWCOUNT` command will still work, while also still providing the actual query result as the output.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##LOG

CREATE TABLE ##Log
(
    ProcName NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ExecutionTime DATETIME
    ,TotalRowsReturned INT
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @numRows INT = RAND()*(50-5)+5;

    SELECT TOP (@numRows) *
    FROM sys.objects

    INSERT INTO ##Log
    (
        ProcName,
        ExecutionTime,
        TotalRowsReturned
    )
    SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@@ROWCOUNT

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

GO


EXEC TestProc
GO 5

SELECT * FROM ##Log
```

Comment: Yes, I know the @@ROWCOUNT but unfortunately it's not for me. In my stored procedure I only have a select statement which must be also the output.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think this answer is still valid so I am going to leave it as is, but I will post a separate answer that I believe will better suit your needs.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I went ahead and edited the my answer here, as it seems my previous examples are a bit generic for the question you've asked.